# For Poisson GLMs, when does the residual deviance follow a chi square distribution?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, likelihood-ratio, chi-squared-distribution, deviance

According to Generalized Linear Models by McCullagh and Nelder (I am looking at the 2nd edition, 1999), the deviance function is defined as
$$D(y; \hat{\pi}) = 2[l(\tilde{\pi}; y)- l(\hat{\pi}; y)]$$

This is the residual deviance, that is, the difference between the perfectly fitting model and the model of interest. They state two assumptions, the second being the point of confusion for me, in the context of Poisson regression. The assumption is "The approximation is based on a limiting operation in which $\dim(Y) = n$ is fixed, $m_i \to \infty$ for each $i$, and in fact $m_i\pi_i(1 - \pi_i) \to \infty$." In Categorical Data Analysis (3rd ed, page 137) Agresti rephrases this as "For a Poisson or multinomial model applied to a contingency table with a fixed number of cells $N$, Section 16.3 shows that the deviance has an approximate chi-squared distribution for large $\{\mu_i\}$."
$$D(y; \hat{\pi}) \to^d \chi^2(n-p)$$

Well, in that case, my question is this: In Poisson regression, does residual deviance approximately follow a $\chi^2$ distribution only when our data can be described by a contingency table where the number of cells does not increase as we increase the sample size?

I am interested in a particular case. For example, say we are walking around and asking different cats and dogs how many friends they have. The cats and dogs answer. Some have few friends, some have many. We record the number for each. Here is some data from the survey:

| number of friends | animal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dog |
| 10 | cat |
| 0 | cat |
| 5 | dog |
| ... | ... |
| 2 | dog |

Now, maybe we want to know whether cats or dogs have more friends. We decide to use a Poisson GLM to model this.
$$E[y|x] = \exp[B_0 + B_1x] \\ y \sim \textrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$$
where x is the categorical variable, say 0 for cat or 1 for dog.

Based on what Nelder/Agresti have to say about deviance, it would seem that the residual deviance goodness-of-fit test for the Poisson model is not valid for this kind of data. This would be because $n$ is not fixed; the number of parameters in the saturated model is dependent on the number of observations, increasing as we add more observations. It appears, however, that this test is commonly used for data of this sort (though with more covariates) when using Poisson regression. Hence my confusion.

This question is addressed similarly [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249905/why-does-the-glm-residual-deviance-have-a-chi-squared-asymptotic-null-distributi) (and in other places) but the part of the answer that considers the Poisson case does not answer my question precisely.

Essentially: When fitting a Poisson GLM on the data above, can the distribution of residual deviance be approximated with a $\chi^2$ distribution, or does that invalidate the assumption I mentioned?

Additionally, I am not interested in discussing why a Poisson model is not ideal for this task, or how I should/shouldn't be using deviance in the first place (though I am open to discussing whether or not cats or dogs have more friends). I am primarily trying to figure out if the distribution assumption holds in this simple example.

Comment: The linked answer seems to state fairly explicitly that the residual deviance is *not* asymptotically $\chi^2$ in this case, that the only limit in which it is asymptotically $\chi^2$ is the case where the numbers of "friends" becomes large ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yeah, the linked answer is clear on that. So that's one way in which the given data would invalidate the $\chi^2$ limit. But say all the fitted values were greater than 2 or 3. I was hoping someone could address the assumption contingent on a "contingency table with a fixed number of cells $N$" because I haven't really been able to find much discussion about that, and in many cases it seems to be ignored, or I am missing something.

Comment: @BenBolker Also thanks for the edits!